# WindowsError when calling sc.parallelize()

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to use the `sc.parallelize()` function, but whenever I try to call it, I get the below error:

```python
File "V:/PyCharmProjects/sample.py", line 9, in <module>

input_data = sc.parallelize(sc.textFile("C:\Users\Spider\Desktop\GM_coding\Sample Data.csv"))

 File "V:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 497, in parallelize os.unlink(tempFile.name)

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: u'C:\\Users\\Spider\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\spark-fef6debd-ff91-4fb6-85dc-8c3a1da9690a\\pyspark-6ed523e7-358f-4e3c-ad83-a479fb8ecc52\\tmpxffhfi'
```

Comment: I run out of flag quota... Can you please describe more? Apparently a different process is still accessing the ressource. You have to kill the file that is being used, here: https://superuser.com/questions/2937/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-thats-in-use

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. All I am trying to do is use the parallelize() function. Even on a fresh boot, I get this error. I tried to look for a process that would be related, but could not find any.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant to your error (and cannot test it in Windows), but you are trying to `parallelize` something that is already an RDD (i.e. "parallelized"); from the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile):

> **`textFile`**(*name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True*)
>
> Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an
>   RDD of Strings.

You don't need (and shouldn't use) `sc.parallelize()` here; the output of `sc.textFile` is already an RDD. You should simply go for

```python
input_data = sc.textFile("C:\Users\Spider\Desktop\GM_coding\Sample Data.csv")
```

See also the example in [the quick start guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell).